# Server side rendering not working in Angular 7

Tags: angular, angular7, server-side-rendering

The error:

> Error: You must pass in a NgModule or NgModuleFactory to be bootstrapped     at View.engine (C:\ssr\dist\server.js:39238:23)     at View.render (C:\ssr\dist\server.js:123884:8)     at tryRender (C:\ssr\dist\server.js:121592:10)     at Function.render (C:\ssr\dist\server.js:121544:3)     at ServerResponse.render (C:\ssr\dist\server.js:130425:7)     at C:\ssr\dist\server.js:135:9     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\ssr\dist\server.js:123312:5)     at next (C:\ssr\dist\server.js:123060:13)     at Route.dispatch (C:\ssr\dist\server.js:123035:3)     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\ssr\dist\server.js:123312:5)

Even though I followed the [official document](https://angular.io/guide/universal).

Comment: Can you please show your code?

Comment: i just created the new project and added ssr using ng add @nguniversal/express-engine --clientProject [project name] and then run the these commands npm run build:ssr && npm run serve:ssr

Answer (score 0):

This is being addressed here
[angular/angular-cli#13868](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/13868)

You can try using a snapshot build of **@angular-devkit/build-angular**

```
npm install git+https://github.com/angular/angular-devkit-build-angular-builds.git
```

then rebuild your project

```
npm run build:ssr
```

Comment: basically problem with windows ( C drive ). when i just start working in D drive, its working